# How to remove blank space between column of listview wpf?

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

[I want to remove blank between Symbol column and Price column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci601.png)
HorizontalAlignment doesn't work

**My code:**

```
<GridViewColumn Width="80" Header="Symbol">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="200" Background="Blue" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Symbol}" Width="auto" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
<GridViewColumn Header="Price" Width="90">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding LastClose, StringFormat={}{0:N2}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: It's unclear from your red circle what blank space you want removed (from the header, or from the data cells?).  It might be better to show a red rectangle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not ideal, but have you tried setting a negative right margin E.g "0,0,-10,0" or tried adjusting the Padding property on the Grid.

As a side note, i'm not sure you neew Width="auto" in the TextBlock.

Comment: Thanks. i'm using margin ="-6,0". it's work